# How to combine elements of two uneven lists in python

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have three lists:

```
proteins = ["1ab1_P.xyz", "1wav_P.xyz"]
ligands = ["DMSO_L.xyz", "MOH_L.xyz", "EOH_L.xyz"]
results = [5.2, 5.0, 6.7, 4.1, 3.9, 0.22]
```

I want to get a result like:

```
output = [
    '1ab1DMSO5.2',
    '1ab1MOH5.0',
    '1ab1EOH6.7',
    '1wavDMSO4.1',
    '1wavMOH3.9',
    '1wavEOH0.22'
]
```

The idea is that each element could be computed like

```
def an_output(protein, ligand, result):
    return protein.split('_')[0] + ligand.split('_')[0] + str(result)
```

The pattern is that each protein should be matched up with each ligand in a specific order (3 * 2 = 6 pairs), and each of these matched up with a corresponding result in sequence.

I have found that the code

```
from itertools import cycle     
aa = [ele for comb in (zip(cycle(list1), list2) for ele in comb]
```

can help with simple lists, but I can't implement it because I need to use split as well in the elements of my lists.

How I can achieve the desired result regardless of the lists' length?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. I can't understand what you expect `.split[0]` to do. Please show an example with *actual values* in the inputs (something that someone else could copy and paste, and not get `SyntaxError` or `NameError`), and show the *exact desired corresponding* result. If you want the result to be a list (which makes sense), then show a list rather than 6 separate variables.

Comment: That said: try to write a function that can take one of the `proteins` values, one of the `ligands` values and one of the `results` values, and compute the corresponding value for the `outcome`; *then* try to figure out how to write logic *using that function* to iterate.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what `.split[0]` means, as that's not normal Python. Would you provide the outcomes as literals instead?

Comment: Please add some synthetic data to your question and show required output

Comment: You are right and thanks for your response.

Comment: I tried to edit to clarify the pattern in the output, according to my understanding - I also wrote the function I mentioned, because you basically had that code already and it just needed some typos fixed.

Comment: Thank you, you wrote what I wanted in a much more precise way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you're looking for...

```
from itertools import product
from functools import cache

proteins = ["1ab1_P.xyz", "1wav_P.xyz"]
ligands = ["DMSO_L.xyz", "MOH_L.xyz", "EOH_L.xyz"]
results = [5.2, 5.0, 6.7, 4.1, 3.9, 0.22]

@cache
def prefix(s):
    return s.split('_')[0]

output = []

for (p, l), r in zip(product(proteins, ligands), results):
    output.append(f'{prefix(p)} {prefix(l)} {r}')

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
['1ab1 DMSO 5.2', '1ab1 MOH 5.0', '1ab1 EOH 6.7', '1wav DMSO 4.1', '1wav MOH 3.9', '1wav EOH 0.22']
```

**Note:**

Spaces inserted into output for clarity